# Why do I get a different output from analogous Linq queries?

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

I am trying the following code in LinqPad 5 (specifically 5.26.01)

```cs
     IEnumerable<string> breeds = new List<string>{
        "Fantail",
        "Lahore",
        "Bokhara Trumpeter",
        "Rhine Ringbeater",
        "Birmingham Roller",
        "Pomeranian Pouter",
        "Racing Homer",
        "Archangel"};

    IEnumerable<string> GetAllBreedsContainingLetter_Fluent(IEnumerable<string> breedlist, string letter)
    {
        return breedlist
            .Where(breedname => breedname.Contains(letter.ToUpperInvariant()) || breedname.Contains(letter.ToLowerInvariant()))
            .OrderByDescending(breedname => breedname)
            .Select(breedname => breedname);
    }

    IEnumerable<string> GetAllBreedsContainingLetter_Query(IEnumerable<string> breedlist, string letter)
    {
        return breedlist = from b in breedlist
                            where (b.Contains(letter.ToUpperInvariant()) || b.Contains(letter.ToLowerInvariant()))
                            orderby b descending
                            select b;
    }

    var breedsFluent = GetAllBreedsContainingLetter_Fluent(breeds, "R");
    breedsFluent.Dump();

    var breedsQuery = GetAllBreedsContainingLetter_Query(breeds, "R");
    breedsQuery.Dump();
```

I think the two functions should be analogous but I noticed something odd about the output in Linqpad.  The first `.Dump()` is identified as an `IEnumerable<String>`; the second `.Dump()` identifies as a `IOrderedEnumerable<String>`.

[image: LinqPadOutput]

Is this something about the queries I'm running or is it an artifact of Linqpad?  I haven't found anything from Googling.

Comment: It seems that the query version is getting executed out of order if that is the case.

Comment: Maybe the fluent syntax is smart enough to ignore the useless `.Select(breedname => breedname)`. It serves no purpose and, while it works for your contrived example, no one would do that in practice.

Comment: @itsme86 Good point; turns out if I remove the unneeded `.Select` from the fluent then they both work the same.

Comment: @itsme86: You are correct. The compiler removes the trivial select *unless doing so would return the original collection*. That is to say, `from x in y select x` is not optimized to `y`.  It's generated as `y.Select(x=>x)`.  If someone is doing `return from x in y select x;` it's probably because they want a read-only view of collection `y`.

Comment: See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/05/12/trivial-projections-are-usually-optimized-away/ for more details on this feature.

Comment: That's a very interesting (and good) thing to know about that detail of what happens under the hood @EricLippert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In query syntax the transformation is such that when you have a trivial projection (projecting an item to itself) it *only* generates a `Select` call when that trivial projection is the *only* operation in the query.  Since your query contains other operations, the `Select` is elided entirely, for performance reasons.

A proper translation of that query syntax query into method syntax would skip the `Select`.  The way to replicate the behavior using query syntax would require something like a second query, to do the trivial projection.